# Changes in specific heat and energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation

When working on problems where the temperature raises considerably over the ambient temperature, the effect of temperature changes on the different variables in the heat equation may not be negligible. Taking the varying nature into account, the heat equation becomes

$$u' c(x,u)\rho(x,u)=\nabla_x \cdot (K(x,u) \nabla u) +Q(x,u),$$
where $u(x,t)$ is the temperature.

The motivation is, for example in air the specific heat changes with temperature in the following way, other parameters may change even more. The question is, how should changes in the specific heat be addressed from energy conservation standpoint?

[image]

More precisely: Should changes in specific heat $c(u)$ release or add energy to the system through the term $Q$ as the temperature changes? Usually the total of $c\rho u$ is the [energy that should be conserved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138658/energy-in-the-heat-equation). With this interpretation the total of $\int c \rho u$ should be constant and thus if $c(u)$ changes with temperature, energy must be added or subtracted through the term $Q$ to conserve $\int c \rho u$.

However even with variable $c(u)$, adding and subtracting energy $Q$ from an initial condition seems to recover the initial condition. So it is possible to define energy of the system differently with variable $c(u)$, I believe the conserved quantity with variable $c(u)$ is something like the total of $u(x) \rho(x) \int_0^u c(u,x)du$ instead.

Assuming no corresponding change in $Q$, in a CDF scheme such as finite volume method the above conservation holds only in the limit as $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$. Are there popular schemes to ensure conservation of energy?

Comment: Please define $Q$ precisely. It is a constant source or does it depend on other parameters?

Comment: @Chemomechanics That is the question, as temperature changes should change in the specific heat be accounted for as an energy source $Q$? In other words, should changes is specific heat due to temperature changes release or tie up heat energy?

Comment: In the equation you wrote, $Q$ is a separate energy source completely independent of the specific heat (e.g., a resistive heater, or a chemical reaction, or convection from the surrounding environment). The equation without $Q$ already accommodates a temperature-dependent specific heat; there's no need to adjust for this effect by adding a new term.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Well thank you for answering the question. "Completely independent" is a strong claim, $Q$ is not even independent of the temperature due to melting etc.

Comment: I took it as a constant because you’ve written it to be independent of $u$ and $x$. That’s why I asked for clarification.

Comment: Although the question involves thermodynamics, it does seem to be about  numerical CFD schemes capable of conserving energy over finite integration steps. I suggest you migrate it to an appropriate forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should changes in specific heat $c(u)$ release or add energy to the system through the term $Q$ as the temperature changes?

The answer is *no*.

Your equation looks like the unsteady conduction equation. The heat term $Q(u,x)$ is independent of the heat capacity and depends on the set up of your problem. This term is the external heat input at position $x$: it might be zero (if no heat added/removed by external sources at position $x$), constant, a function of $x$ only, a function of $u$ only, etc. None of this has to do with the heat capacity and whether it is temperature dependent or not. Treat $c(x,u)$ just like $K(x,u)$: a factor in your PDE that depends on $x$ and $u$.